# Can exclude a div (class) from html doc. ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I have an HTML page that has external javascript, mostly facebook plugins and other social plugins, which slow down the load time of whole page. I have a javascript loader that hides everything except "Loading" and the AJAX loader gif until whole page has completely loaded.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    var tid = setInterval(function() {
        $(".bc").css("display", 'none'); // .bc is my body , so here i hided 
        //  it becouse not every object is fully loaded
        $(".bc").fadeOut("fast");
        if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) 
            return;
        clearInterval( tid );  // here exits from loop when page is complete
        $(".bc").fadeIn(100);  // and then i show on users the content
        $("#cssmenu").css("display", 'block');
        $("#loader").fadeOut(40); // hide loader
        $("#myiframe").css("display", 'block');
        $(".mastfoot").css("display", 'block');
        $(".bc").css("display", 'block');
    }, 500 );
</script>
```

My page looking somehow like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- head stuff -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bc">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
    <div class="social plugins">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show the body content even before the social plugins load.

Comment: You can call those externla JS files asynchronously after your page is loaded...

Comment: Call those external plugins in `onload`